# Unknown Color Format Exception during Pdf Creation from html to pdf Using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

```
Document document = new Document();
string str = Pagehtml;

//writer - have our own path!!!
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Server.MapPath(".") + "parsetest.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
//here when it parse the html gives exception unknown color format should be #RGB
ArrayList htmlarraylist = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(str), null);

//add the collection to the document
for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
{
    document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
}
```

this is my code in which i am parsing the html code but when it parse the html it gives exception of Unknown Color format

Answer (score 0):

You will need to post the HTML for us to see exactly what is causing the error. But ultimately the error message should be pretty obvious. Some part of your HTML has some invalid RGB values as far as iTextSharp is concerned. [Per spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#colors) (that links to 5 but its the same for previous versions) all colors in HTML should be in the format `#RRGGBB`. iText, however, does appear to also allow `#RGB` as well, although I expect that it is intended for CSS parsing. Lastly, if you're using CSS you can use `rgb(R,G,B)`.

[Line 260 of the most recent version (5.1.1.2) shows you the line throwing the actual exception.](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/WebColors.cs?revision=233&view=markup#l260)

Comment: thanks for your reply i got the solution for my problem that was due to inline CSS i have used in my page i have define the color in non RGB format now this problem is solved by defining them in RGB  Format.